# Using values from previously dispatched action in the next action in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I'm using `react-redux` and also `redux-thunk`
I have two actions whereby one action is dependent on the other action's result to perform its own action. Below is how my code looks;

```
const file = useSelector(state => state.Files.file)
const handleActions = async () =>{
  try{
      await dispatch(uploadFile(dataForm))
      await dispatch(updateBusiness(params))
  }
  catch(e){
      console.log(e)
  }

}
```

So, I need a value in the response data of `uploadFile()` to perform `updateBusiness()`

I tried using `file` right after `uploadFile()` but I am getting undefined.

```
 const file = useSelector(state => state.Files.file)
 const handleActions = async () =>{
   try{
       await dispatch(uploadFile(dataForm))
       params.file = file
       await dispatch(updateBusiness(params))
   }
   catch(e){
       console.log(e)
   }

 }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: While it's not completely clear what exactly your actions return. But usually it's possible to return a value from action and you can get it into a variable: `const result = await dispatch(uploadFile(dataForm)); await dispatch(updateBusiness({ ...params, file: result.file })`. If the first action is just storing it's result into the state the second action can use it from the state directly aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `useEffect` to check when `file` update

```
useEfect(() => {
  if(file){
    params.file = file
    dispatch(updateBusiness(params))
  }
}, [file])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since dispatch is asynchronous, you need to wait until the state is changed.
Try to move your updateBusiness function inside useEffect with dependency of file.

```
 const file = useSelector(state => state.Files.file)

 // updateBusinessFunction
 useEffect(()=>{
   const update = async () => {
      try {
         const data = params;  //copy value of params
         data.file = file;
         await dispatch(updateBusiness(data));
      } catch (e) {
         console.log('update business error : ', e)
      }
   }
 },[file]) // if params is not constant change it to [file,params]

 const handleActions = async () =>{
   try{
       await dispatch(uploadFile(dataForm))
   }
   catch(e){
       console.log(e)
   }
 }
```

That way `updateBusiness` will use run when `file` state is changed.